# Can't install JDK 7u51 (64-bit) on Windows 2012 R2 "this app can't run on your PC"

Tags: java, windows

I'm trying to install JDK on Windows Server 2012 R2, but I'm getting an error "this app can't run on your PC". I've tried to "Run as Administrator" but I'm getting the same error. I'm using the x64 installer of JDK 7u51 (latest version at the time of this problem).

I can see on this page that JDK 7u51 *should* be certified working as of 7u51: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/config-417990.html

Any ideas how to resolve this?

You can see a photo of the error here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ld3K.png

Comment: See here, seems related: http://superuser.com/questions/518289/this-app-cant-run-on-your-pc-is-displayed-when-running-a-program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the size of the downloaded file. I had this same problem on the same OS with the same JDK version and the problem was the file was not fully downloading. From your screen shot the downloaded file size is 25,795KB which is incorrect: it must be 125.46 MB. To resolve, I got a network administrator involved (and I *think* he downloaded it to another machine and copied it across the network).

Comment: ahaa that was it, thanks!